# matrix to data.frame corrupts when handling factor variable? [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I'm converting some matrix to data.frame and it corrupts when handling factor variables:

```
> class(combn(as.factor(1:50), 2))
[1] "matrix"

# works
as.data.frame( t(combn(as.factor(1:50), 2)) )


# not work when shortened:
> as.data.frame( t(combn(as.factor(1:50)[1:2], 2)) )
  t(combn(as.factor(1:50)[1:2], 2)).1 t(combn(as.factor(1:50)[1:2], 2)).2
1                                   1                                   2
2                                <NA>                                <NA>
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs

# convert to numeric and works
> as.data.frame( t(combn(as.numeric(as.factor(1:50)[1:2]), 2)) )
  V1 V2
1  1  2
```

Can somebody tell me why and how to fix it (converting to numeric fixes it)? Thanks...

Comment: In your matrix, the columns are 'factor' class.

Comment: it's allowed right? matrix supports any single class

Comment: In this case ,it is only 'factor' class.  But, why do you need a `factor` class for numeric columns.  Also, it might be better to convert the first option to factor later if it is needed.

Comment: Hi @akrun thanks man! Because in real problem, I was dealing with some `factor` variable. Of course I can convert it to `numeric` and convert back if needed. What do you mean by first option?

Comment: Perhaps `v1 <- factor(1:50); d1 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(seq_along(v1),2))); d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(i) v1[i])`